# Simple harmonic motion frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I already did part a and b by using kinematics but I'm stuck for the next part

A particle moves along the x axis. It is initially at the position 0.300 m, moving with velocity $0.070 m/s$ and acceleration $-0.330 m/s^2$. Suppose it moves with constant acceleration for $5.60 s$.

- a. Find the position of the particle after this time.
- b. Find its velocity at the end of this time interval.

We take the same particle and give it the same initial conditions as before. Instead of having a constant acceleration, it oscillates in simple harmonic motion for $5.60 s$ around the equilibrium position $x = 0$.

- c. Find the angular frequency of the oscillation. Hint: in SHM, $a$ is proportional to $x$.

This is what I tried and I am within 10 %. I kept all the decimals so there is probably something that I am missing

$$f = \frac{1}{T} = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\sqrt\frac{k}{m} $$

$$ \omega = 2\pi f$$

The given period is $5.60$ sec (I believe so but the wording is not completely clear).

The frequency is then:

$$f = \frac{1}{T} = .1785714 \: Hz $$

$$\omega = 2 \pi f = 1.1219973 \: rads/sec$$  and i get within 10%

Comment: I think this is fine as a homework question as the OP has made a sensible attempt at the question and wants to know why it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the question, although I agree its not that clearly written. I do not think time is the period of the motion (is there a part d?).

I would use the initial position, velocity and acceleration to work out $\omega$.
(Use the hint in the question).

Comment: why did the solution Autolatry suggested work.  
they give us constant acceleration of -.33 for parts and b. for part c we don't know if the object in fact has an acceleration of -.33 at position .3  how come is it correct?

Comment: @Petrarca Yes you do. It says it is the **same** particle at the **same** initial conditions. You have to read the question very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In SHM, the acceleration of a moving body is related to it's displacement by;
\begin{equation}
a(x) = - \omega^{2} x
\end{equation}
It's easy to see from your question, that we have
\begin{equation}
-0.33 = -0.3\omega^{2}
\end{equation}
From which we obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
\omega^{2} &=& \frac{0.33}{0.3} \\
           &=& 1.1
\end{eqnarray}
From which
\begin{equation}
\omega = \sqrt{1.1} = 1.049 s^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: It's important to remember that I have clearly taken the positive sqare root in this example.

Comment: For homework type questions you should try and avoid just giving the answer. Instead say where people are going wrong or suggest a suitable method and encourage them to work it out for themselves. See [this meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: my problem with that approach is that they give us constant acceleration of -.33 for parts and b. for part c we don't know if the object in fact has an acceleration of -.33 at position .3  . am i missing something? (ALTHOUGH IT IS CORRECT BUT I DONT SEE HOW)

Comment: The question states that intitially the body moves from an initial displacement of $o.3$m for $5.6$s with constant acceleration.